# Не работают темы кроме стандартных Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Установил WP, все хорошо, ошибок нет, но когда выбираю тему, получаю чистый белый экран, в консоли ошибок нет define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); ничего не дает, гугл молчит. может кто сталкивался? хелп[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работают только стандартные темы! остальные-белый екран

Comment: Смотрите иерархию шаблонов WordPress. Если ошибок нет, значит подключен пустой шаблон

Answer (score 0):

Вчера при выборе новой темы была чистая белая страница, после перезагрузки ПК темы применяются как надо. может кому-то поможет